# Solving differential equation $(3t-x) \ dt + (3x-t) \ dx = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked the following problem:

> Solve differential equation $(3t-x) \ dt + (3x-t) \ dx = 0$.

By noticing that it was an exact differential equation, I did the following:

$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = -1\\
\\
\begin{cases}
F_x &= 3t-x\\
F_y &= 3x - t
\end{cases}
\\
\begin{cases}
F &= 3tx-\frac{x^2}{2} + g(t)\\
F &= 3tx - \frac{t^2}{2} + h(x)
\end{cases}
\\
\begin{align*}
g(t) &= - \frac{t^2}{2}\\
h(x) &= - \frac{x^2}{2}
\end{align*}
\\
\therefore \quad 3tx-\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}=C
$$

The problem was comparing my answers with the textbook's. Is my answer wrong? Did I make a mistake somewhere?

**Textbook's answer** $3t^2-2xt+3x^2 = C$

Thank you.

Comment: In fact, $F_t=3t-x$, $F_x=3x-t$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(3t-x)dt+(3x-t)dx=0\\ 3\left( tdt+xdx \right) -\left( xdt+tdx \right) =0\\ \frac { 3 }{ 2 } d\left( { t }^{ 2 }+{ x }^{ 2 } \right) -d\left( xt \right) =0\\ 3\left( { t }^{ 2 }+{ x }^{ 2 } \right) -2xt=C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(3t-x) \ dt + (3x-t) \ dx = 3tdt-xdt+3xdx-tdx=0$$
$$3tdt+3xdx=xdt+tdx$$
$$3(tdt+xdx)=(xt)'$$